# Zigzag subsequence

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

As part of a homework assignment I'm asked to describe an O(mn) algorithm to find the length of the longest zig-zag sub sequence. The overall topic for this assignment is dynamic programming. As described in chapter 15 of [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

A zigzag pattern is for example (2, 4, 1, 4) or (1, 2, 1) or (6, 1, 3, 2). While (1, 2, 3) and (4, 3, 2) are not. But the input could be (1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1) which should result in (1, 2, 1, 4, 1). But for now the number of elements denoting the longest zig-zag sub sequence is simply stored at the end of the subl array.

Below is my attempt at an algorithm. I'm trying to use a bottom up approach.

```
zigzag(A)
    signs[] ={0}
    subl[] = {1}
    for i= 1 to n
        for j = i - 1 downto 0
            sign = signs[j]
            if sign = 0 OR (sign<0 AND A[i] - A[j]>0) OR (sign>0 AND A[i] - A[j]<0)
                subl[i] =subl[j] + 1
                signs[i] =A[i] - A[j]
                break
```

As far as I can analyse the outer for loop runs n times and the inner loop also runs at most n times. Which means that my algorithm actually is mn = nn = n^2. However I'm somewhat worried because my algorithm looks a lot like bubble sort.

Comment: So what's the question?  It sounds like you have an algorithm and you believe its running time is as required -- so what's the issue?  You haven't shared with us the problem statement (for instance, you haven't defined $m$, $n$, or a zig-zag subsequence), so I'm not sure how we could comment.  For instance, are you sure that $n \le m$?

Comment: I'm just not sure if it's right. And I'm worried that I completely have misunderstood the assignment. I try to define the zig-zag subsequence by the examples I have given. M seems to be defined as the largest element in the input. But some of my fellow students say that it's an error... if it's not clear I'm quite confused by the whole thing.

Comment: "Please check my answer" questions are off-topic for this site.  This applies, e.g., when the question includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer: thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. Or, visit us in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined your notation, but if $m<n$, then an $O(n^2)$-time algorithm (like yours) isn't necessarily a $O(mn)$-time algorithm.  So, depending upon the definition of $m$, your algorithm might be too slow.

(Think about the case where $m=7$ or where $m=\sqrt{n}$, for instance.)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. m is the largest element of the input. However some of my fellow students said that it was a mistake. But I'm not sure... thus I'm trying to get some clearance here.

Comment: @user672009, this is not a discussion forum.  Please read the comments and links and feedback I've given to you, then edit your question as best as you can to make it on-topic.  Don't drop clarifications into the comment threads; edit the question to make it clearer.  On this site, we expect that the question needs to be understandable, without reading the comment thread.  Also: my answer applies even with that clarification.